# NPV calculation based on formula: stuck creating sequences

Tags: r

I am trying to replicate some formula

[image]

Where;

- r is the discount rate,
- a is AGE
- bi(a) is the decile_INCOME
- f(a,bi(a)) is mean income as a function of AGE and decile

The data I have looks like:

```
# A tibble: 150 x 3
     AGE decile_INCOME     mean
   <dbl>         <int>    <dbl>
 1    81             9  347816.
 2    86             2   22700.
 3    60             3   39750.
 4    91             9 3459166.
 5    24             9   54927.
 6    64             4   43966.
 7    65             3   23289.
 8    37            10  360649.
 9    69             4   67781.
10    38             2   31198.
```

So for each Age and decile_Income I want to calculate the NPV something similar to the below (for a small sample of the data and for AGE = 25).

[image]

a_bar is the index, so using the example above then a = 25, then a_bar > a, therefore a_bar ∈ {26, 27, 28, 29...}

My attempt: (I am stuck with trying to create the set of sequences for "a_bar")

```
rate = 0.05
npvs <- df %>%
  mutate(a_tilde = 34567890, # stuck here
         discount = 1 / (1 + rate) ^ (a_tilde - AGE),
         NPVs = mean * discount)
```

EDIT: Full data:

Had to remove the data due to carácter limit.

EDIT:

Looking at the following observations:

In the code we group_by `decile_INCOME` & `AGE_REF` - but should we group_by `decile_INCOME` & `AGE`?

```
   AGE decile_INCOME mean_AGEbin_decileInc households_per_AGE_decile REF_AGE disc_rate disc_mean
1   20             1              4092.739                        12      18 0.9070295  3712.235
2   20             1              4092.739                        12      19 0.9523810  3897.847
3   20             1              4092.739                        12      20 1.0000000  4092.739
4   20             2              5392.289                        12      18 0.9070295  4890.965
5   20             2              5392.289                        12      19 0.9523810  5135.513
6   20             2              5392.289                        12      20 1.0000000  5392.289
7   20             3              6826.857                        12      18 0.9070295  6192.161
8   20             3              6826.857                        12      19 0.9523810  6501.769
9   20             3              6826.857                        12      20 1.0000000  6826.857
10  20             4              9029.341                        12      18 0.9070295  8189.879
11  20             4              9029.341                        12      19 0.9523810  8599.373
12  20             4              9029.341                        12      20 1.0000000  9029.341
13  20             5             13333.046                        12      18 0.9070295 12093.466
14  20             5             13333.046                        12      19 0.9523810 12698.139
15  20             5             13333.046                        12      20 1.0000000 13333.046
16  20             6             19746.410                        12      18 0.9070295 17910.576
17  20             6             19746.410                        12      19 0.9523810 18806.105
18  20             6             19746.410                        12      20 1.0000000 19746.410
19  20             7             26497.320                        12      18 0.9070295 24033.850
20  20             7             26497.320                        12      19 0.9523810 25235.542
21  20             7             26497.320                        12      20 1.0000000 26497.320
22  20             8             32910.684                        12      18 0.9070295 29850.960
23  20             8             32910.684                        12      19 0.9523810 31343.508
24  20             8             32910.684                        12      20 1.0000000 32910.684
25  20             9             39661.593                        12      18 0.9070295 35974.234
26  20             9             39661.593                        12      19 0.9523810 37772.946
27  20             9             39661.593                        12      20 1.0000000 39661.593
28  20            10             60083.094                        12      18 0.9070295 54497.137
29  20            10             60083.094                        12      19 0.9523810 57221.994
30  20            10             60083.094                        12      20 1.0000000 60083.094
```

When I do that I get a plot which looks like:

[image]

Which doesn`t look as smooth as yours….

Comment: It looks like the source data is sparse, with large, irregular gaps between AGE within each decile. It will be simpler to solve if you have more complete data, or a process in mind for how to impute missing values.

Comment: I Will add more data now!

Comment: I added the full data set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the npv back to age 18:

```
library(dplyr)
rate = 0.05
df %>%
  arrange(decile_INCOME, AGE) %>%
  group_by(decile_INCOME) %>%
  mutate(disc_rate = 1 / (1+rate) ^ (AGE - min(AGE)),
         disc_mean = mean * disc_rate) %>%
  # try View()  at this stage to review how the discount is applied
  summarize(npv = sum(disc_mean))

# A tibble: 10 x 2
   decile_INCOME       npv
           <int>     <dbl>
 1             1   196051.
 2             2   381107.
 3             3   539085.
 4             4   717242.
 5             5   925751.
 6             6  1185537.
 7             7  1582346.
 8             8  2796287.
 9             9  6955914.
10            10 51016943.
```

To discount back to age 25, filter out earlier ages and do the same:

```
df %>%
  filter(AGE >= 25) %>%
  arrange(decile_INCOME, AGE) %>%
  group_by(decile_INCOME) %>%
  mutate(disc_rate = 1 / (1+rate) ^ (AGE - min(AGE)),
         disc_mean = mean * disc_rate) %>%
  summarize(npv = sum(disc_mean))

# A tibble: 10 x 2
   decile_INCOME       npv
           <int>     <dbl>
 1             1   226399.
 2             2   465403.
 3             3   670195.
 4             4   897065.
 5             5  1165181.
 6             6  1504068.
 7             7  2023148.
 8             8  3694092.
 9             9  9479113.
10            10 71109533.
```

Or, to get all npvs for all ages, we could make a copy of every row for every possible reference age, calculate discounts based on the reference age, and then summarize based on both decile and reference age:

```
df %>%
  uncount(max(AGE), .id = "REF_AGE") %>%
  arrange(REF_AGE, decile_INCOME, AGE) %>%
  mutate(disc_rate = 1 / (1+rate) ^ (AGE - REF_AGE),
         disc_mean = mean * disc_rate) %>%
  group_by(decile_INCOME, REF_AGE) %>%
  summarize(npv = sum(disc_mean))
```

In chart form:

```
  [chain above...] %>%
  ggplot(aes(REF_AGE, npv, color = decile_INCOME, group = decile_INCOME)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I think this is it! Is there anyway I can keep "AGE" in the final data, I see you construct "REF_AGE" but does "1" correspond to "18", "2" = "20" etc.? In the data the ages start at 18 and end at 95, in your final output it starts at 0 and ends at 95, where did the additional 170 observations come from? (the `dim` of the `df` is 780 and the final `dim` is 950. The graph looks like it should :)

Comment: REF_AGE is the reference age for discounting. For simplicity in setup, it includes all years back to 1 year olds, hence the extra rows. use `filter(REF_AGE >= 18)` afterwards to just include adults.

Comment: Thanks :) So I could just rename "REF_AGE" to "AGE" and it would be the same?

Comment: Yes, at the end. I gave it a different name in the body of the calculation since for each row the discount rate is based on the difference between the AGE in that row's stat, and the REF_AGE which is the age to discount back to.

Comment: One question; where you have `  group_by(decile_INCOME, REF_AGE) %>% ` should it not be `  group_by(decile_INCOME, AGE) %>% ` - i.e. grouping by `AGE` instead of `REF_AGE`. We want to sum up the NPVs for each "decile" and "AGE" - I have added a sample of the output in the original question.

Comment: I don't believe so. What I mean by REF_AGE is the one age at a time that is the reference point for the discounting, summing all the future ages' discounted cash flows together.

Answer (score 0):

just to understand, in your data you have multiple observations for the same age:

```
    AGE decile_INCOME         mean
17   19             2     4033.668
73   19            10    76454.049
101  19             3     5019.783
123  21             5    15358.319
34   22             2     9486.804
35   22             8    35868.648
98   22             3    13057.680
```

what is the value of f that you enter in your formula for a given age: the average of those values? for example what is f(22,b_i(22))? can you create a dummy variable D that is 0 for all ages less than a and then pass D*mean instead of mean? then you do not have to the inequality constraint in the sum ...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes there are multiple observations for the same AGE but they are not exactly "multiple" since there are 10 deciles for each AGE category.